# hook and eye orbital sander problem

Tags: tools, sander

I have have a hook and eye orbital sander. My problem is that the sanding disc come flying off after a few minutes. Is there anything I can do to increase the duration the discs are in place ?

Comment: More details on the sander like model, picture, etc would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean hook and loop (Velcro and similar)? I don't recognize the term "hook and eye" in conjunction with Sanders.

Comment: Are you saying the entire pad comes off, which is a known issue with Porter Cable orbital replacement pads, or just the abrasive disc comes off of the pad?

Comment: It's very important to have a match between pad and disc.  Crossing brands makes this a nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using the correct adhesive system for the pad, there are two instances where this will happen:

1) Your pad is old and will no longer hook the loop, you'll have to replace the pad, generally about 15$ and you can easily do it yourself.

2) Your pad is incompatible with the sander you're using(rare if you're using the same system). It happens sometimes even with the same system sanders where the hooks on the sanding pad are agressive as are the loops on the disc, causing the loops to tear off the disc damaging the hooks on the pad. This may have happened in the past.

Comment: 3) You were half-asleep and tried to stick the abrasive side of the sandpaper to the hooks. Don't ask how I know about this mistake...

Comment: +1 on replacing the pad. I have gone through 2 pad replacements on my RO sander. Online auction sites has them really cheap and with free shipping usually. Look up the make and model number of your sander, and if need be, the type. Confirm the part number you find with a  few vendors, since you are buying online and I am sure you will want to get the proper part the first time. Remove a few screws that hold the pad on and install the new one.

Answer (score 1):

I have owned five different brands of sanders that use hook and loop attachment. Every sander, after four or five uses will no longer hold the paper. I purchased a  new pad for the Porter Cable sander and again after four or five uses it will no longer hold the paper. 
The new pads cost about $10. That is too expensive. It is difficult to find a sander that doesn't use the hood and loop system. The solution in my opinion is to buy a replacement pad that utilizes adhesive pads.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

Others have correctly identified that the backing plate with the hooks is a replaceable wear item on the sander.

What others haven't mentioned is that *your technique with the tool can accelerate its wear.* Let the sand paper do its job and also learn to recognize when it is worn out. Don't exert excessive pressure on the sander in an attempt to make the sand paper cut better. Pressing down hard does help wring out that last bit of life from a piece of paper but it also crushes the hooks on the backing plate. In other words, it causes premature failure of the backing plate.